# Electronic antispark plug (MOSFET I think?) stays always closed

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

I'm trying to setup a remote electronic switch for my lighting system which consists of a constant current driver and an LED. When working at full power around 6 A at 52 V go through the switch.

[image: schematics]

What happens is, and I've tried this with 2 different ones now, when the CC driver is setup for very low current (around 0.1 - 0.2 A) I can switch the system on and off fine. When I increase to full power, I switch on, it works, but then it stays on and I can't switch off anymore like the switch is stuck. I tried unsoldering and now both red and black wire show continuity through even at low current and won't go back to functional again.

These are the switches I tried:

- https://lunacycle.com/remote-on-off-solid-state-switch/
- https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B08N69J5B4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Both are rated for 60 V and way more current than I'm using.

Any idea why is this happening as to me it looks like I stay well within the specifications?

Comment: Add a schematic of how you have connected everything together.

Comment: Is the switch before or after the CC driver?

Comment: This "stuck switch" behaviour does match what MOSFETs often do when their limits are exceeded.  So I'm reasonably sure you broke it somehow. The question is why and how to solve it. Just to avoid confusion: the "antispark switch" is not a MOSFET, it's a circuit with a bunch of stuff in it, probably including a MOSFET as the main component that does the actual switching.

Comment: The switch is before the CC driver as after the CC driver the voltage might get above the 60V limit. I have a potentiometer to increase or decrease the voltage, and the CC pot is set to limit the current to 5A to the LED at 54V after the CC Driver, which I'm monitoring and it's not going above. I incuded a schematic in the first post